# File Compression

Tags: java, algorithm, compression

I am trying to compress a string by turning it in to letters and numbers. Example:

`INPUT: AAAAbbWWWW`

`OUTPUT: A4-b2-W4`

Here is the problem I am running in to:

When I run it with the query "aaaaaaa", I get "a7".

When I run it with the query "aaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", I get "a12-b2-b2-b2-b2-b2-b2-b2-b2-b2-b2-b2-b2-b2-b2".

My code is

```
List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < toCompress.length(); i++) {
        chars.add(toCompress.charAt(i));
    }
    List<String> bits = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++) {
        char toMatch = chars.get(i);
        int matching = 1;
        for (int dontuse = i; dontuse < chars.size(); dontuse++) {
            int x = dontuse + 1;
            if (x >= chars.size()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (chars.get(x) == toMatch && (x - 1 == matching)) {
                matching++;
            }
        }
        if (!bits.contains(toMatch + "" + matching)) {
            bits.add(toMatch + "" + (matching + 1));
            i = i + matching;
        }
    }
    String compressed = "";
    for (int y = 0; y < bits.size(); y++) {
        if (y == (bits.size() - 1)) {
            compressed += bits.get(y);
        } else {
            compressed += bits.get(y) + "-";
        }
    }
    return compressed;
```

Can anyone tell me how to stop it from only counting to two in every segment but the first?

Comment: Why don't you use a map with key = char and value = #iteration ? That would be straightforward. If you need your output as a string, it is also fairly easy to convert the map into the string you want.

Comment: I see. I will try that and post my results. Thanks.

Comment: @isanco In the map keys are not ordered. I guess, here output should ordered as the input. because he is compressing the string.

Comment: Just what I was about to say. It just throws it out completely randomly now.

EDIT: What I am thinking now, is putting each character in a list only once, and putting them in order based on the list.

Comment: consider introducing a threshold to keep a recoding from being longer than the original run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple algorithm for your problem would be the following:

```
private static String compress(String str) {
    StringBuilder compressed = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < str.length()) {
        int length = 1;
        while (i < str.length() - 1 && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+1)) {
            length++;
            i++;
        }
        compressed.append(str.charAt(i)).append(length).append('-');
        i++;
    }
    return compressed.deleteCharAt(compressed.length() - 1).toString();
}
```

It goes like this: while the character of the input String at index `i` is the same as the following character, we increment a `length`. As a result, `length` is then equal to the number of following characters that are the same.

When we hit a different character, we stop the loop, store the current character and its length, and repeat all this again for the next character.

Note that this algorithm will "compress" the String `b` into `b1`. You did not specify how it should behave on such Strings. If you don't want to this, you can simply add a check on `length` before it is appended to the current compressed String.

Comment: Thanks! This is much simpler than my version.

Comment: Curious, what would the big O look like? N^2 or no?

Comment: @BenKnoble I think this is O(N) since the String is compressed in only one-pass.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I fixed it. Here is what I did:

```
    List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    List<Character> oChars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < toCompress.length(); i++) {
        chars.add(toCompress.charAt(i));
    }
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (!oChars.contains(c)) {
            oChars.add(c);
        }
    }
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++) {
        try {
            map.put(chars.get(i), map.get(chars.get(i)) + 1);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            map.put(chars.get(i), 1);
        }
    }
    String compressed = "";
    for (char c : oChars) {
        int amount = map.get(c);
        compressed += c + "" + amount + "-";
    }
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(compressed);
    b.replace(compressed.lastIndexOf("-"), compressed.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, "" );
    compressed = b.toString();
    return compressed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your logic doesn't really work. In fact, it's pretty hard to understand what you are trying to do here.

The place where you add to `bits` is the important part, because at the end you basically display what's in `bits`. So let's look at that part.

```
    if (!bits.contains(toMatch + "" + matching)) {
        bits.add(toMatch + "" + (matching + 1));
        i = i + matching;
    }
```

So it's important to see where you change the `matching`.

The first loop runs fine verifying against the `a`. But your problem is in this condition:

```
        if (chars.get(x) == toMatch && (x - 1 == matching)) {
```

`matching` is 1 at the beginning of the inner loop. So as soon as you are into ranges of `i` that are beyond 0 and 1, `x - 1` is not going to be equal to `matching`, and that means that `matching` will not change, it will stay at `1`.

So except your first character, you'll never get a correct number in `matching`, because it will never be incremented. There is no point in comparing a running index to a count.